# A fila de edições sugeridas é curta demais

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, edição, filas-de-análise

Parece que a [fila de edições sugeridas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review) só comporta 12 posts. Quando está nesse tamanho, os links de editar das perguntas e respostas ficam desabilitados. No momento somente [dois](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe) [usuários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/179/talles) têm acesso à fila, e mesmo que fossem 10, 12 posts é muito pouco. Não incentiva as pessoas a editarem, que é uma das coisas legais desse engine.

Podemos ampliar esse limite? Para, quem sabe, 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fila pode conter 40 edições, em determinado momento. Enquanto isso pode ser restritiva no início, agora que mais de uma dúzia de pessoas têm privilégios completos de edição que deve ser suficiente.

Comment: Who translated for you? :) It's perfect!

Comment: I'm getting better at using google ;-P